# Troubles sorting an ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I need to show a list sorted by countries with the minimum days to reach 50,000 cases in the .csv file. The countries are displaying by each day in each line, so I have to read each line to figure it out how many days. In the end it should print the number of countries that achieved 50,000 cases in the minimum days, in ascending order.

[Spain Beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDM5f.png)

[Spain Ending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmUtX.png)

So in this case it should show 84 days to reach 50000 cases.
In this code if it passes 50000 cases, it won't enter the while loop, so I guess I'm doing something wrong. And I'm not sure if in this one I'm giving the country the minimum number or if I'm just giving the line of the day.

```
// Constructor for class Country
    public Country(String isoCode, String continent, String location, LocalDate date, int totalCases, int newCases, int totalDeaths, int newDeaths, int newTests, int totalTests, int population,
                   double older65, double cardiDeathRate, double diabetesPrevalence, double femaleSmokers, double maleSmokers, double numBeds, double lifeExpectancy) {
        this.isoCode = isoCode;
        this.continent = continent;
        this.location = location;
        this.date = date;
        this.totalCases = totalCases;
        this.newCases = newCases;
        this.totalDeaths = totalDeaths;
        this.newDeaths = newDeaths;
        this.newTests = newTests;
        this.totalTests = totalTests;
        this.population = population;
        this.older65 = older65;
        this.cardiDeathRate = cardiDeathRate;
        this.diabetesPrevalence = diabetesPrevalence;
        this.femaleSmokers = femaleSmokers;
        this.maleSmokers = maleSmokers;
        this.numBeds = numBeds;
        this.lifeExpectancy = lifeExpectancy;
    }
```

This is the loader code:

```
    public boolean load(String filename) {

        p = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)).skip(1).forEach(p -> loadLine(p));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void loadLine(String line) {
        String [] data = line.split(",");
        p.add(new Country(data[0],
                data[1],
                data[2],
                LocalDate.parse(data[3),
                Integer.parseInt(data[4]),
                Integer.parseInt(data[5]),
                Integer.parseInt(data[6]),
                Integer.parseInt(data[7]),
                Integer.parseInt(data[8]),
                Integer.parseInt(data[9]),
                Integer.parseInt(data[10]),
                Integer.parseInt(data[11]),
                Double.parseDouble(data[12]),
                Double.parseDouble(data[13]),
                Double.parseDouble(data[14]),
                Double.parseDouble(data[15]),
                Double.parseDouble(data[16]),
                Double.parseDouble(data[17])));
    }
```

And this is the sort one:

```
public List<Country> sortedByMinDays(Country p1, Country p2) {
        int min=0;
        List<Country> lp = new ArrayList<>(p);
        while(p1.getIsoCode()==p2.getIsoCode() && p2.getTotalCases()<=50000){
            min=min + 1;
            p2.setMinDays(min);
        }

        for (int n=0; n<lp.size(); n++){
            if (p2.getMinDays()<p1.getMinDays()){
                int aux = p1.getMinDays();
                p2.setMinDays(p1.getMinDays());
                p1.setMinDays(aux);
            }
        }

        return sortedByMinDays(p1, p2);
    }
```

Comment: List has a sort method. Use that.

Comment: But I have to introduce specific methods right?

Comment: @PedroMoreira In order to sort an ArrayList you need to use Collections.Sort(list). Because it's a list of a class you created, you should also create and add a Comparator to define the order between two objects.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)

Comment: @Raz But on that case all the Collections.sort will have that Comparator define method right? And I need to make more sorts

Comment: @Abra was just to give more detail, its not allowed?

Comment: @PedroMoreira No, you can still call Collections.sort without the comparator, the comparator is just another parameter you send with your sort call. You can Also make more than one comparator and use sort with the one you'd like. You can also look at examples here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-sort-java-examples/

Comment: @Raz Thanks. More 1 question, you can give me one tip on how I can make a single Country receive the variable that i will create by counting the lines that is a single day for each country? And reproduce that for every country I have?

Comment: @PedroMoreira I'm sorry but you should create a different question thread for that question. Also make sure that your question stands in Stack Overflow community rules and add enough information so it will be easier to help.